# How to add div id name to array

Tags: javascript, html

At the page I have these divs:

```
<div id="question-688">
</div>

<div id="test">
</div>

<div id="stats-654">
</div>

<div id="answer-636">
</div>

<div id="someDiv">
</div>
```

I would like to create an array with these numbers: 688, 654, 636. So when id of div is started with `question` or `answer` or `stats`, I want to add number belongs to this ID to array. How can I do this via javascript?

Comment: Do you want the whole id or just the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plain css selector with method `document.querySelectorAll`.
I used `Array.prototype.map.call` because the previous method returns a `NodeList` not an `Array`, then you can use map and pass it a function to extract the ids of your divs.

### [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/LFSrG/)

```
var selector = 'div[id^=stats-],div[id^=answer-],div[id^=question]',
    ids = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function (div) {
        return div.id.split('-')[1]|0; // this returns the id as an integer
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divIDs = [];
var r = /\d+/;
for (var i =0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].id.length > 0 && ( divs[i].id.indexOf("question") !=-1 || divs[i].id.indexOf("answer") !=-1 || divs[i].id.indexOf("stats") !=-1 ))
        divIDs.push((divs[i].id).match(r));
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/P3LPn/

Answer (score 1):

Only ONE instruction if you use jquery :

```
var yourArray=$('div[id^=stats],div[id^=question],div[id^=answer]').toArray().map(function(e){return $(e).attr('id').split('-')[1]}) ;
```

**See fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/LBc5u/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working jsBin : http://jsbin.com/pecaj/1/edit

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [];
var divArray = document.querySelectorAll("div"); 
 for(var index = 0; index<divArray.length; index++) {

  var id = divArray[index].id;
  if(id.match(/\d+$/)) {
    arrayOfNumbers.push(parseInt(id.match(/\d+$/),10))

}

}
console.log(arrayOfNumbers)
```

It fetches the number for div ids and adds them to an array.

Hope its useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this? Create a map and them use the map to refer to your DIV's

```
var map = {};
// add a item
map[key1] = value1;
// or remove it
delete map[key1];
// or determine whether a key exists
key1 in map;
```